Function Return Value Casting
I am currently using the ShellExecuteA function, and when reviewing the return value I was a little confused on how to handle it. Specifically, the part where it says :

The return value is cast as an HINSTANCE for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications. It is not a true HINSTANCE, however. It can be cast only to an INT_PTR and compared to either 32 or the following error codes below.

Thus, when I write my following code block to handle an error condition, I get a warning message when compiling with Visual Studio 2022:
// Open Documents folder so shortcut looks legitimate
if (ShellExecuteA(NULL, "explore", dirPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL) < 32) {
    return 1;
}

warning C4047: '<': 'HINSTANCE' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
Whereas if i use type casting as I would on a variable, the issue seems to dissapear.
// Open Documents folder so shortcut looks legitimate
if ((INT_PTR)ShellExecuteA(NULL, "explore", dirPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL) < 32) {
    return 1;
}

If I understand correctly, the return value of ShellExecuteA function is getting casted to an INT_PTR, as stated in the documentation?
Can I get some information around this?

It seems you've already found the information yourself? However, C does not allow to compare a pointer type with an integer so if you get no warning, that means INT_PTR is not an int pointer but something else. These type systems were not created by the best and brightest programmers in the world... Mingw Windows runtime seems to define it as typedef __int64 INT_PTR,*PINT_PTR; So there's an even worse type PINT_PTR available too, for all of our clown programming needs...

The code with the (INT_PTR) cast is correct. However your code will just distinguish between "success" and "failure", the error number returned by ShellExecuteA ist lost..

@Lundin INT_PTR is the Microsoft version of the uintptr_t type.

@nielsen Why would you compare a type like that against 32 error codes? None of this is making any sense.

@Lundin It is a Microsoft API, it is not supposed to make sense to the outside world.

@sunflower You should compare <= 32. The API says the value will be greater than 32, i.e. > 32 on success.

@nielsen API literally stands for Application Programming Interface. The very purpose of its existence is to allow the outside world to interact with it.

@Lundin We are in complete agreement, but this is Microsoft. You can probably pay to get a certificate saying that you understand their API. If the API was clear, that entire business would be destroyed.

ShellExecuteA is somewhat weird (and deprecated even if this is not documented by Microsoft). It shouldn't be used anymore, instead there is ShellExecuteExA, which is less weird and has less limitations.

Hard to get behind advice to call ShellExecuteExA. For sure don't call old legacy ShellExecute. Do call ShellExecuteEx. And call the W version. That way you get proper error handling, and Unicode text.

@Lundin "INT_PTR is not an int pointer but something else." - Correct. It is an integer type capable of storing a pointer. "These type systems were not created by the best and brightest programmers in the world..." - That's a somewhat unique opinion. INT_PTR is the ABI alias for the equivalent intptr_t type introduced in C99. I will be genuinely surprised to learn that everyone in WG14 is a "clown".

@IInspectable When did I comment on C99? You are putting words in my mouth and misquoting everything said. The clowns here are those who decided not to use industry standard C99 but re-invent the wheel by coming up with their own non-standard terms. Or to hide pointers behind typedef, which everyone knows is a cardinal sin, with broad consensus among non-clown programmers.

@Lundin "The clowns here are those who decided not to use industry standard C99 but re-invent the wheel" - That's like saying: "Why didn't NASA send a Space Shuttle to rescue the Apollo 13 astronauts?" With the obvious out of the way, there's a far more subtle detail here: Them "clowns" did not re-invent anything. They created something genuinely new: An ABI. An INT is exactly 32 bits wide, using two's complement with no trap representations. An int, on the other hand, is pretty much whatever. It's unsuited to form the basis of an ABI.

@DavidHeffernan I was suggesting ShellExecuteExA because the OP was using ShellExecuteA. But your right, the A versions shouldn't be used anymore.

@IInspectable Err, the C standard never forced any implementation to support all implementation-defined forms of int. Rather, it kind of expects the implementation to pick one single representation. Besides, I don't see what that has to do with MS refusing to follow industry standards, since implementation-defined integer types have been in C since C90 and MSVC is mostly conforming to the year 1990 version of C. Will they ever properly upgrade it to the year 1999 version, then they have access to industry standard uintptr_t and need not reinvent it.

@IInspectable Btw an uint32_t is _also exactly 32 bits wide using two's complement with no trap representations or padding bits. It was introduced in C exactly 25 years ago. All good compilers support it since for ever - since the previous millennium.

@IInspectable As for looking closer at __int64 INT_PTR,*PINT_PTR; beyond the hiding pointers behind typedef clown practice - there has to my knowledge never existed a CPU with negative address space. Creating one by saying that negative addresses in virtual address space is kernel space is just weird. Proper design would have been to use an unsigned type and then mark the MSB in that one for kernel address space.

@Lundin "Rather, it kind of expects the implementation to pick one single representation." - Right. And an ABI solves the problem of interoperability across implementations where two implementations make different choices. "Btw an uint32_t is also exactly 32 bits wide using two's complement" - True. Iff it exists. uint32_t was introduced as an optional feature and remains optional to this day. Besides, work on the Win32 API predates C99. I don't understand how two's complement representation is relevant in the context of unsigned types.

@IInspectable No, it's not an optional feature if the system can handle 32 bits. Which is true for every system I've ever heard of including old 8 bit microcontrollers. So what's the problem?


If I understand correctly, the return value of ShellExecuteA function is getting casted to an INT_PTR, as stated in the documentation?

No, you misunderstand the docs.  This ...


The return value is cast as an HINSTANCE for backward compatibility
with 16-bit Windows applications.
It is not a true HINSTANCE, however.
It can be cast only to an INT_PTR and compared to either 32 or the
following error codes below.


... is poor wording, but that's somewhat mitigated by context in the original source, which leads into it with:

If the function succeeds, it returns a value greater than 32. If the function fails, it returns an error value that indicates the cause of the failure.

Overall, I think this conveys more clearly what the docs are trying to say:

The return type is HINSTANCE for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications, but the return value is merely an integer code converted to that type.  The only valid use for it is to convert it to type INT_PTR for comparison with the number 32 and / or with the error codes below.  Success is indicated by that value comparing greater than 32.

In particular, it is your responsibility to perform the conversion to INT_PTR, as you do in your second example by casting.
As a minor additional point, this ...

if i use type casting as I would on a variable

... suggests a misunderstanding about casting.  Cast operators such as (INT_PTR) are unary operators, analogous in that sense to ! or unary -.  A cast operation converts the operand value to the data type specified by the operator.  Cast operations are in no way specific to use with variables.  Their operands can be any kind of expression, subject to C's general limitations on which type conversions are defined.

Factually correct, but the real answer is: Don't call ShellExecute[A|W](). Ever. Call ShellExecuteExW() because it knows how to report errors and manage ownership. Bonus reading material: How do I test that return value of ShellExecute against 32?.

That's likely good advice, @IInspectable, but it does not answer the question actually posed.  Happily, however, you have now provided that advice as an addendum.
